# Chrome form validation message appearing off screen on Windows 10

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome

I'm on Chrome version 55 and its native form validation messages are appearing outside of the browser window on Windows 10:

[image]

Even worse is if a user has their window maximized, as the message isn't visible at all and leaves the user hanging.  The form doesn't submit because of the validation error but nothing is shown to the user.  :-(

This problem seems to only appear when using Chrome on Windows, as I've also tested the following environments and they seem to work fine:

- Chrome 55 on macOS
- Firefox on Windows 10
- Internet Explorer on Windows 10
- Edge on Windows 10

[image]

Is this behavior consistent with what other people are seeing? Any workarounds?  Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q4qg5f3t/1/

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="address" value="" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Update (2016-12-18):**
I filed a bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675476

This was also discussed here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z7zelQwtd5k;context-place=forum/chrome

**Update (2016-12-19):**
Turns out that this problem is related to screen pixel density: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675476

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug, that message remains on the screen and it's very annoying. I noticed it a few days ago too :(

Comment: @Cristy What's your screen pixel density?  It looks like this problem only happens when not running at 100%. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675476

Comment: I have 2 monitors and one TV connected, the TV is 1080p at 125% text scale ratio, the main monitor is 1440p at 125% ratio and the secondary monitor is 1080p at 100% ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. There does appear to be error with messages persisting between tabs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your screen pixel density?  It looks like this problem goes away when running at 100%. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675476

Answer (score 0):

This problem turns out to be a bug in Chrome for high dpi screens in Windows.  A patch was submitted on Nov. 19, but I'm not sure when it's going to appear in the stable branch:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/5debc705a0b892bd2dcf82ec7672147268083957